# use javascript to open :target css3 modal popup

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am using this **css3 modal** https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_target_modal

Not sure how to open and close it with **javascript** or **jQuery**

This opens on click via `:target`

Tried with `$('#beforeYouGo').click()` and `document.getElementById("beforeYouGo").addEventListener('click', hide, false);` with no results.It's first time when I use this css3 modal and not sure how to handle it.

I need to open it when user is moving mouse to leave the website, I have the function for that but can't target the modal.

Any help please?

Comment: You can't trigger that modal using JS as it's completely reliant on the CSS `:target` pseudo selector. If you want a modal which can be programmatically controlled through JS, look for another library. There are literally thousands.

Comment: Just removed the library for this css modal to increase speed :)

Comment: Understandable, but the compromise with speed is configurability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with this, until I find a better solution:

on mouse leaving I use `modal.addClass('active');` the css:

```
.modal.active,
.modal:target {
  display: table;
  position: absolute;
}
```

and for close `modal.removeClass('active');`